# Application lags if started from init.d?

Tags: process, python, init

I have a program (pre-compiled binary) that, when started manually on linux, runs fine. It has a CLI that I use to enter commands. This program is a software router, I can connect to it's CLI to adjust it's settings.

However if I want to start it up at boot time the program goes very slowly, unusably so. If there is information being printed to the screen for example, it will be printed out in chunks, as if there was a slow baudrate, that kind of thing. Every command I enter is like this, information is printed very slowly.

What could be happening, what is different from me running this manually after boot rather than from init.d with S99 or something? If I stop the process and relaunch it manually it works fine.

This python script is what is called from init.d:

```
import subprocess
application_pidfile = "/var/run/application.pid"
command_line=["start-stop-daemon", "-q", "-p", application_pidfile, "-S",
              "-m", "-b", "-x", "/bin/application"]
subprocess.call(command_line)
```

What I wonder is why would it still be going slow an hour after boot? Yet if I just stop it and start it manually it will run fine even a few seconds after boot? Even if I set a delay, such as start this process a few minutes after boot the same issue occurs.

Could it be starting in some slow "socket" mode or something?

Comment: You start it from init, yet it produces output to the screen?  Processes started via init should be daemons and produce no output.  Can you explain more about where the output goes, when, and why?  And please include your init script.

Comment: Obviously this is not the case for other init process, and since it is also not the case in general for others, *you need to provide a reproducible example* if you want an answer. @Mikel Note he used that "for example" -- even if the process does print to the screen, it should not be slowed down particular except to the extent that it is interleaved with other processes.

Comment: @TAFKA Sure. But how it prints to the screen could be an important piece of the puzzle.  Does it print to `/dev/console`?  Directly or via syslog for example?  What does it try to print and when?  We don't have any information.

Comment: @Mikel The line in init.d calls the python script I have edited above. This runs in the background, I can connect to the application when it is running. The application is a software  router. I connect to it's console. Here is where all the slow output is observed

Comment: 'If there is information being printed to the screen for example, it will be printed out in chunks.' This sounds like the normal buffering you get when a program doesn't output to a terminal. Perhaps you are just looking for the program to be line buffered so that each line is output immediately (or completely unbuffered). Maybe the reason you think it is slow is just because the output is left in buffer for a while. How is it that you see output when the program is started by an `init` script?

Comment: What happens if you start it using `start-stop-daemon` from a root shell after boot?

Comment: @Mikel I have a python command that starts it from start-stop-daemon after boot and that works completely fine. I will try doing it from a  root shell and get back to you, but I imagine it works perfectly.

Comment: @Graeme I am able to connect to the cli of the software router via a session id, bring it to the foreground. The lines are printed out to my terminal. It looks to buffering very slowly yes, I just dont know why. Especially as this only happens if I start it from boot. Any time after boot and it behaves like a normal router console

Comment: Try `start-stop-daemon -q -p application_pidfile -S -m -b -x /bin/application &>/dev/null </dev/null` and see if you have the issue

Comment: @Graeme that just directs all lines to null so when I connect I see nothing :)

Comment: ? `start-stop-daemon` should do the equivalent of this anyway if you use the `-b` option or else it can't be detached from the terminal. I was wondering if it still inherited its buffering from `start-stop-daemon`. Try `stdbuf -o4096 -e4096 start-stop-daemon -q -p application_pidfile -S -m -b -x /bin/application` in there terminal, maybe this will reproduce the problem. Also, can you tell us which program you are using?

Comment: @Graeme I will test again maybe I messed up. i have noticed something odd, I generally start it with a python script calling start-stop-daemon and there is no delay. but when I tried from a  root shell with the same command the issue occurs! like Mikel asked me to check about. I'll try your posts now

Comment: whenever I call it with any command froma  shell this issue occurs, so i guess it may not be associated with booting and is associated with start-stop-daemon. I'm not sure why calling start-stop-daemon with python was masking this issue and making everything work well. I am using clish to call the python btw

Comment: I'm confused, how exactly did you recreate the issue? If you have the problem when running from a root shell, but nothing when running the exact same command from a normal user shell, then the problem is likely caused by environmental variables and nothing to do with buffering.

Comment: How about this: `start-stop-daemon -q -p application_pidfile -m -b -x /usr/bin/stdbuf -S -- -oL -eL /bin/application`. Running this command from a shell should stop the issue if it is buffering.

Comment: @Graeme I think I solved it, just testing. Apparently starting it from python set a nice level of 19, but starting it from boot/root sets it as 0, which seems to slow the whole system down for some reason, adding -N 19 to boot should work when I try

Comment: So the issue here is different default nice levels for users.

Comment: @Paul, could well be it, but -N 19 will only make the program go slower! A negative number is more favourable to the process. Also consider `renice` before you connect to it if it is running all the time.

Comment: @Graeme It did fix it, it was rather unintuitive as you suggest. Apparently it having more cpu cycles was a bad thing, must have been slowing down whatever was in charge of printing information to the screen by hogging resources? 19 would like a charm, solved, thanks a lot for your help btw

Answer (score 1):

Modern init systems such as systemd and upstart run multiple threads of execution, and even with the original init, things may be forked during the boot process (you've already said yours does, for example).

This means your process is running at the same time as other processes, and any output will be interleaved with their's:

```
   Process 1 says "I'm here"
   Process 2 says "I'm here"
   Process 1 says "Doing my thing..."
   Process 3 says "I'm here"
   Process 3 says "Doing my thing..."
   Process 1 says "Still busy..."
   Process 2 says "Doing my thing..."
```

Note the order here is random beyond start priority; an `S05` will *begin* before a `S70` process, but when they finish in relation to one another is indeterminate unless one completing is a specific prerequisite of the other.

If you've ever done any threaded programming, you'll be familiar with this horse race.  Because the processes are running simultaneously, they do not interleave in an orderly fashion -- hence in my example, `Process 3` gets to do several things before processes that started earlier get to do the equivalent.  Etc.  This is just happenstance and will not be the same every time.

**Boot is a busy time for the system** -- many things are happening actively at once.  So if you compare the execution time to running the process alone subsequently, it will be slower, because in the latter case it does not have to compete with many (or, in significant terms, any) other active processes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I realise boot should slow things down all right, and that other things have to be done. I've edited in more information above, I'm starting a software router with start-stop-daemon from inid.d. This will run continuously -I can attach and detach from it to enter commands, so what I wonder is why would it still be going slow an hour after boot? Yet if I just stop it and start it manually it will run fine even a few seconds after boot? Even if I set a delay, such as start this process a few minutes after boot the same issue occurs.

Comment: That I can't say.  *You should add those details to the question too.*  I've added the python tag in case this is relevant (but I'm not a python user, so don't have any thoughts about that).

Comment: Okay. I'm gonna leave this answer up for posterity.

Comment: Good idea, it's informative.